# Mysql server has gone away: not running any big scripts

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-ec2

One of my servers running a PHP app has been experiencing problems with mysql:

```
PDOStatement::execute(): MySQL server has gone away 
PDOStatement::execute(): Error reading result set's header
```

I have gone through many of the similar questions but in my case, I am not running any long running scripts that does any big sql query. It just frequently happens in all of the pages of the website. After one refresh it would work, then after another refresh MySQL would punch me in the face again. Been going on for a day now.

No changes to the code have been made as to my knowledge and no server reconfiguration was also done. It just started happening over night which is why this is leading me to believe that a vulnerability in the application or server may have been exploited.

I have tried increasing `max_allowed_packet` in the mysql.conf but it did not help. Has anyone already experienced anything like this?

Comment: Have you gone through [this list of possible causes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html)?

Comment: Check mysql error logs to find out the root cause of the problem.

Comment: It appears that the mysql service is actually restarting several times in a minute. I'm considering the possibility of corrupted data but I've run `mysqlcheck` on all my schemas and they all return OK. Going to keep banging my head on the wall for the mean time.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the EC2 instance running the database was already maxed out in terms of storage. I didn't know that running out of physical storage would cause the mysql service to restart over and over.

I was killing myself for something that was so easy to fix. Thanks for that link, it was the very first reason in my case.

```
You (or the db administrator) has killed the running thread with a KILL statement or a mysqladmin kill command.
```

Only that it was the kernel that was killing mysql.